# Доступ с компьютера к БД приложения на устройстве Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, sqlite

Здравствуйте.

Занимаюсь разработкой под андроид. Использую базу данных SQLite. В процессе разработки было бы удобно "сливать" фаил базы данных и с помощью сторонних средств смотреть что же там лежит.

Когда у меня на телефоне стояла кастомная прошивка, я мог делать это без проблем. Насколько я помню у меня был доступ к папке **data** в которой лежат все файлы приложений.

Теперь у меня стоит родная прошивка и доступа нет.

Какой выход? можно ли без лишний шаманств получить доступ к файлу базы данных приложения? хотя бы на время разработки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть 3 способа:

1. Начиная с 14-й версии Intellij IDEA можно получить доступ к БД SQLite устройства (реального или эмулятора). Доступ дается через DataSource - нечто типа JDBC драйвера, то есть можно смотреть, делать запросы и проч. - но руками пощупать сам собственно файл не получится. [Почитайте здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp13/accessing-android-sqlite-databases-from-intellij-idea.html) Работает только для платной версии Intellij IDEA (версия Ultimate)
2. Можно тупо получить root на свое устройство, далее вы получите доступ к каталогу /data
3. Можно установить на самом устройстве SQLite3 + командную консоль (все это можно найти на Google Play Market) и через командную строку в самом устройстве (опять же нужен рут).

Comment: Я хорошо помню, что и на 13 IDEA Ultimate, и скорее всего на 12 тоже, плагин Database Support уже был.

Comment: Он был всегда, но не поддерживал коннект к SQLite на Android девайсе

Comment: понятно. все упирается в рут. Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Если первый вариант, то работает и без рута

Answer (score 2):

В IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate есть плагин Database Support, который позволяет полностью получить доступ к БД устройства во время разработки: просматривать таблицы, изменять содержимое, удалять и добавлять записи и тд. - полноценный редактор базы данных подключенный прямо к базе данных разрабатываемого приложения. Это нереально удобно.

В бесплатных IDE, что для Eclipse, что для Android Studio/IDEA Community ничего подобного нет. Гугл обещал в туманной перспективе для AS сделать такой плагин, но сроки задвинуты куда-то за горизонт.

К всем трем бесплатным IDE можно подключить плагин [SQLiteManager](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) ( [о подключении к AS/IDEA](http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fd%2Fmsg%2Fadt-dev%2FJqw9VslC_Vw%2FLBMZG_M3ydkJ) ). Это конечно жалкое недоразумение по сравнению с database support ультимата, но позволяет просматривать БД на устройстве.

Так же вы можете вытянуть свою БД через православный adb.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно установить в проект библиотеку http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ и воспользоваться браузером Chrome DevTools.
В его арсенале достаточно много дополнительных плюшек. (Просмотр сетевого трафика, View Hierarchy, Database Inspection)

Answer (score 1):

В Eclipse и Android Studio имеется DDMS File Explorer, через который вы можете выгрузить базу из эмулятора, (из реального без root наверное не сможете).
Так что выход использовать эмулятор.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Как здесь уже писали, можно извлечь файл БД с устройства. Но если устройство настоящее, в каталог приложения попасть нужно суметь, потому что каталог доступен только самому приложению.

Для этого есть команда `run-as`, которая позволяет выполнять команды с правами определенного приложения. В примере ниже `com.yourpackge.name` — id приложения, `filename.db` — имя файла с базой.

```
adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackge.name ls /data/data/com.yourpackge.name/databases/”
adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackge.name cat /data/data/com.yourpackge.name/databases/filename.db > /sdcard/filename.sqlite"
adb pull /sdcard/filename.sqlite
```

Comment: Еще несколько идей здесь: http://jollydroid.ru/notebook/2016-11-11-Root-SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, с помощью [дополнительной библиотеки](https://github.com/bartwell/ultra-debugger).