# Плагин для управления БД в Android Studio

Tags: android, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Подскажите если есть плагин для управления базой данных в Android Studio?

Я просто не так давно начал изучать Android, но из документации понял что рекомендуют работать с SQlite, поэтому именно для нее.

Comment: вы так пишете, как буд-то существует одна-единственная база данных. Какой именно БД?

Comment: Я просто не так давно начал изучать Android,но из документации понял что рекомендуют работать с SQlite,поэтомуименно для нее!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Доступ с компьютера к БД приложения на устройстве Android](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428779/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-android)

Answer (score 1):

Можешь использовать [SQLiteManager](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

Comment: А вас не смущает словосочетание **Android Studio** в вопросе?

Comment: @metalurgus его [можно подключить](http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fd%2Fmsg%2Fadt-dev%2FJqw9VslC_Vw%2FLBMZG_M3ydkJ) и к Android Studio , там тоже есть Android Device Monitor -  DDMS, хотя толку от этого плагина мало.

Comment: @metalurgus Tools - Android - Android Device Monitor, и попадаешь в DDMS, где открываешь File Explorer, и в нем уже можно пользоваться этим обозревателем БД

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос поднимался на stackoverflow.com [See database file(content) via Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/see-database-filecontent-via-android-studio). Или вы можете посмотреть информацию более детально [сдесь](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite).