# Менеджер для отображения данных бд sqlite в рантайме

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

подскажите наилучший способ отображения базы данных приложения в рантайме и изменений в ней. Или  расскажите какие-то эффективные способы работы с бд, чтобы не приходилось после каждого запроса скачивать файл с устройства и открывать в какой-то программе. На текущий момент использую carnary версию студии(там есть database inspector), но постоянно крашит эмулятор, поэтому пользоваться на постоянной основе практически невозможно. Буду рад услышать какие-то успешные и распространенные практики среди разработчиков.

Comment: используйте реальное устройство для тестов, если эмулятор падает постоянно, что странно. Лучше database inspector нет способа мониторить базу. Можно попробовать пару не очень стабильных плагинов для idea или любой sqlite manager для андроид {отдельная программа на телефон), подключиться им к своей базе в data/data, но нужен root

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430500/177345

Comment: @pavlofff я думаю, что приложение в эмуляторе падает именно на отладке из-за сырости карнари версии, в обычной все нормально